# how to properly use fstream and passing data in a char array?

Tags: c++

In this function what I have to do is pass the strings from txt file in char and do some operations. My only problem is on pass file from txt to char. how i should fix it?

```
char* foo(string& input){
stringstream ss;
ss<<input;
char *elements=new char[32];
elements[32]='\0';
ss>>elements;       //next part code not written because useless
```

Comment: Unrelated: In `elements[32]='\0';` `elements[32]` does not exist. `elements` is only valid from 0 to 32.

Comment: Do you know the length of the string beforehand (i.e. before you compile the code)?

Comment: It is really unclear what you are trying to do. You don't need `stringstream` to copy a `std::string` into a `char[]` buffer, you can use [`std::string::copy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/copy) instead for that, or use a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) instead of a `char[]`. If you want to parse out a single word from the `std::string`, use `std::string::find()` or `std::find_if()` to find the delimiter then use that offset to `copy()` characters, or use `std::string::substr()`. Stay away from raw pointers if you can.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can store data in a char array from a file:

**Source File**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("Input File.txt");
    char Array[50] = { ' ' };
    inFile.get(Array, 50);
    cout << "Output : " << Array << endl;
    inFile.close();
}
```

**Text File**

```
    Enter Text Here
```

If you want i can make a dynamic array for you which will have the exact size as the string (Data you input) from file or use vectors because they can easily be expanded and shortened in late binding(means: during program execution).